# Subsetting a data set by condition

Tags: r, self-study

‘Warpbreaks’ is a built-in dataset in R. Load it using the function `data(warpbreaks)`. It consists of the number of warp breaks per loom, where a loom corresponds to a fixed length of yarn. It has three variables namely, breaks, wool, and tension.

a.) Write a code (Hint: a logical expression) that extracts the observations with wool type A and tension level M. Assign it to the object `AM.warpbreaks`.

b.) For the `AM.warpbreaks` data set, compute for the mean and the standard deviation of the breaks variable for those observations with `breaks` value not exceeding 30.

My code for 4a) (However, it didn't work. Can somebody help me how to solve this problem?)

```
warpbreak <- data(warpbreaks("breaks", "wool", "tension")) 
AM.warpbreaks <- c('','type A','level M')
```

Comment: This question is certainly off topic here, and I doubt it will be on topic anywhere else. Do your homework yourself, please.

Answer (score 2):

Here you go:

```
data(warpbreaks)
warpbreaks <- data.frame(warpbreaks)
AM.warpbreaks <- subset(warpbreaks, wool=="A" & tension=="M")
```

Comment: fyi warpbreaks is already a data.frame, but +1 for not giving a complete answer to a homework question.

Answer (score 0):

Jonas Berge's answer is nice, but I would avoid the use of `subset()` function, which is said to cause trouble sometimes (only to use for convenient display, as I remember). Here is a solution using `which()`; this function is also said to create troubles sometimes, but I've seen it less on forums, so I suppose it happens less. Also, a drop of unused levels following the subset:

```
data(warpbreaks)
warpbreaks <- data.frame(warpbreaks)
AM.warpbreaks <- warpbreaks[ which(warpbreaks$wool=="A"  & warpbreaks$tension=="M"), ]

library(gdata)
AM.warpbreaks  = droplevels(AM.warpbreaks , reorder=FALSE)
```

Comment: I've never had any problems with subset(), but it seems much slower than using the which() approach so I avoid it in more complex tasks. It is easier to write and understand for a beginner, so that's why I thought it was appropriate here.

Comment: @Jones Berge: I've never had any problem as well, but I've read somewhere that using `subset()` can lead to -if I'm correct- "unexpected consequences". So the advice was to use it for display, rather than "true" code (e.g. functions). As I don't have time to check my data.frames after subsetting them, I tend to avoid the function. And I do think your answer is good, I just wanted to bring some more info.

Comment: Ok, hadn't heard about that so thanks. But I never use it in functions anyway due to speed issues.